# Is it possible to use different navigation pages per site on one code base in EpiServer 7?

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

We have one website right now and have created a new one with the same codebase.

But we need to change how navigation works on the new site that will impact the first one.

Are we able to create multiple navigation pages and specify which site uses which navigation page? Or do they intend us to have separate code bases for things like this?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing Episerver-specific about this, really.

You could add a setting (e.g. a `bool` property) to the start page type, and use that to determine which navigation to load.

For example, if that start page property is `true`, you load different partial view(s) for the navigation.

That is, if you have multiple websites within the *same web application* (multiple websites defined in admin mode).